# Interpolate javascript in html loaded from mongoDB with React

Tags: reactjs

The problem is this: I bring the HTML from MongoDB and charge it in react with: `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {{__html: products.content.title}} />`. It is displayed correctly. Now, what I want is that in the HTML that I load, I can have variable settings like for example: `<h2> {{product.title}} </ h2>` and that when loading them from the database, React I get them correctly . I am loading the HTML in React with the webpack loader 'html-loader'. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to link your component code?

Comment: Are you generating the HTML on the server side, or is it stored directly in your DB as a string?

Comment: stored directly in DB as a string

Comment: if `products.content.title` is <h2>'hello ${name}'</h2>, 
I need that when loading it in React, ${name} I loaded the value correctly and not raw html

Comment: https://gist.github.com/cesarcf/b16607df3d845db2f1b5ec07d0d2489b @PaulMcloughlin

Comment: any idea? @SrThompson

Comment: The thing is that `<h2>'hello ${name}'</h2>` is not valid HTML, and react doesn't transform HTML set with dangerouslySetInnerHTML into JSX. You could use `eval` to try and execute your code as JS but I don't know if it will work, since JSX it's not really JS syntax. Other option would be using a regex to replace the variable, and that sound dangerously close to making your own templating engine... isn't there any way that you can just query your backend for the data directly?

Comment: I'll have to put it another way. I was trying to load an HTML template from the database and replace the variables in the frontend. Thank you